# Does a git fast-forward merge ever change the merged commit's SHA?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-merge

In other words, is a fast-forward merge guaranteed to produce the same GIT SHA as the HEAD of the source branch that's being merged in?

I tested this behavior in the terminal, and it holds true for my test scenario:

```
$ git rev-parse some-branch
0fc9fba2fb1c8a13556da4a333351bc12909c497

$ git merge some-branch --ff-only
Updating 90c6244..0fc9fba
Fast-forward
 b | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 b

$ git rev-parse HEAD  
0fc9fba2fb1c8a13556da4a333351bc12909c497
```

I can leverage this condition in my tooling, e.g. I tag build artifacts with the source GIT SHA. If fast-forward guarantees no SHA change, I don't have to do some possibly costly rebuild check. The catch is I have to be sure this is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fast forward merge is simply an index forwarding on your branch, without any commit modification, so the hashes will be the same.

Comment: Does index forwarding mean the pointer that says "head of branch A points to commit X" changes to "head of branch A points to commit Y"?

Comment: Yes, it's as you described.